# Unable to Start Debugging on the WebServer

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, visual-studio-2008, windows-xp

While creating the website I choose Location as HTTP and then provided http://172.24.17.188/myProject and it created the project happily.

And I was able to run the project too. But once I have closes the VS2008 and reopened the project , I am getting the following error while trying to run the website.

[image]
**Edit:**
I am able to browse the website by manually typing in browser but unable to run or debug usinh VS2008.

Answer (score 2):

If the website is running on IIS on the same machine then you can attach the debugger to the IIS process. You do this by click on "Debug" then "Attach to process...". Sort the processes in descending order and find the process named "w3wp.exe". Then click the "Attach" button. If you don't see the process then view the site in a browser to allow IIS to start the process.

If the website is running on a different server then you can do the same but you need to run the remote debugging tool (MSVSMON). This means you will need to have Visual Studio installed on the webserver. Run MSVSMON and be sure the firewall doesn't block the connection. Now you click "Debug" then "Attach to process...". Enter the server name that was displaed on MSMON's debug window in the qualifier textbox. If everything is setup properly you will see the remote servers process list. Then you can connect to the "w3wp.exe" process.

These are two ways to debug web applications using Visual Studios and IIS.

Comment: My Website is running on IIS on same machine. But I am not able find "w3wp.exe". I tried also opening the website in browser and then refreshed the process list but still could not find the process

Comment: Try running Visual Studio as "Administrator" and on the "Attach To Process" window be sure "Show processes from all users" is checked. Click the refresh button and see if that shows it.

Answer (score 2):

Do the following changes in your IIS settings

- Make sure that IIS is configured to use Integrated Windows Authentication
- Make sure that HTTP Keep Alives are enabled.

Comment: While this answer didn't directly resolve our issue, we did find the root cause of our issue when we went to check that "HTTP Keep Alives" was selected in the IIS server-level "HTTP Response Headers".  We found a duplicate "HTTP Response Header", and removing that duplicate entry resolved the issue.